# WooCommerce Hide Shipping Methods

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to hide all shipping methods except Local Pickup if the cart total is less than $150.

```
function hide_shipping_for_order_total( $rates ) {
    $order_total = WC()->cart->get_subtotal();

    if( $order_total < 150 ) {
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
            if ( 'local_pickup' !== $rate->get_method_id() ) {
                unset( $rates[ $rate_id ] );
            }
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_for_order_total', 100 );
```

My code works and if the cart total is less than $150 the Local Pickup label appears but for some reason the radio button type is set to hidden. If the cart total is greater than $150, Local Pickup  is available as it should be.

Comment: This is normal, as you have only local pickup active (one shipping method with no other choice), so WooCommerce only displays the label and local pickup is auto selected.

Comment: Of course, that makes perfect sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the below one.

```
function modify_shipping_methods_for_order_total( $available_shipping_methods, $package ) {
    $order_total = WC()->cart->get_subtotal();

    if( $order_total < 150 ) {
        foreach ( $available_shipping_methods as $rate_id => $rate ) {
            if ( 'local_pickup' !== $rate->get_method_id() ) {
                $available_shipping_methods[ $rate_id ]->get_instance()->instance_form_fields['hidden_class'] = '';
            }
        }
    }

    return $available_shipping_methods;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'modify_shipping_methods_for_order_total', 100, 2 );
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your reply but loictheaztec's comment made perfect sense for my issue.